# Javascript createObjectURL.URL fails for MediaStream

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to create an Electron app that takes a screenshot of the screen according to the following guide:

https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/280/creating-screenshots-of-your-app-or-the-screen-in-electron-framework

I'm getting an error while executing inside the developer tools console of Electron:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': No function was found that matched the signature provided.
```

When I `console.log` the stream object that is passed in `video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);` I see that it's of type `MediaStream`.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL the `createObjectURL` can accept "A File, Blob or MediaSource object to create an object URL for.". How can I convert the `MediaStream` that I'm getting into the `MediaSource`?

Answer (score 3):

Attach your stream directly to `srcObject` property instead of using `URL.createObjectURL` function.

Do this:

```
video.srcObject = stream; // new implementation
```

Instead of this:

```
video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream); // old implementation
```

You can read the recommendation in the doc page you've referenced to, in the section: [Using object URLs for media streams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL#Using_object_URLs_for_media_streams).